# NVM fails to install any version of Node.js in Cygwin

Tags: python, node.js, cygwin, nvm

I've already learned that Node.js opted out of supporting Cygwin in the newer version, but NVM can't install the older version either. The error I'm getting:

```
$ nvm install v0.4.12
Additional options while compiling:
######################################################################## 100.0%
C:\Python27\python.exe: can't open file '/home/wvxvw/.nvm/src/node-v0.4.12/tools\
/waf-light': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
nvm: install v0.4.12 failed!
```

*(formatted for readability)*

I think this is because of Python binaries aren't aware of Cygwin-style path (and cannot find `/home/` directory) I tried building from sources (same version) and am facing the same problem). I'm not sure however what to do. I wouldn't like to change Python installed in Windows for Python that can be installed through Cygwin. And if this error isn't just the tip of the iceberg, I'd maybe just change the Makefile.

The question is directed to those who might tell whether it makes sense to try to "fix" the Makefile, or should I just use Cygwin's version of Python (its problem is very buggy `fork`, but I think I could live with that...)

Comment: Maybe I'm stating something that you already know, but I ran into the same trouble until I found out there's a windows installer for nodejs. http://nodejs.org/download/

Comment: Why do you need it to run in cygwin? It runs fine in plain old windows.  If you really do it need it I'd suggest downloading the src and compiling manually: http://nodejs.org/dist/node-v0.4.12.tar.gz

Comment: The majority of users either use posix, or use windows, not the hybrid that is cygwin.  Would linux in a virtualbox not fit your use case?

Comment: MSYS2 supports building node.js (ie: https://github.com/joyent/node/pull/8294 ). Have you looked into using that?

Comment: @generalhenry @AlbertHendriks The reason why you don't simply use a "click installer" for your language engines is the same reason why you don't use a click installer for the various node modules you `npm install`. It's not repeatable, it's bad practice. Put simply, you won't be using the same version of node for the rest of your life, so you need tooling to help transparently manage the usage of the right version according to the project. Ignore this if you are a fire and forget developer who doesn't provide support for projects you create.

Answer (score 0):

Command is not correct , use version without v. Try : **nvm install 0.4.12**